# VS 2013 RC: ICE on variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, visual-studio-2013

This is a reduced test case:

```
template <typename Sig, Sig& S> struct OpF;

template <typename TR, typename ... Ts, TR (&f)(Ts...)>
struct OpF<TR (Ts...), f> {};

double foo() { return 0; }

struct RegFun {
  template <typename R, typename ... Ps> RegFun(R (*)(Ps...)) {
    typedef OpF<R (Ps...), foo> OP;
    OP();
  }
} FNRegisterer(foo);
```

The compiler says:

```
ice2013_4.cpp(11) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\template.cpp', line 22679)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
    ice2013_4.cpp(11) : see reference to class template instantiation 'OpF<R (void),double foo(void)>' being compiled
    with
    [
    R=double
    ]
    ice2013_4.cpp(13) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Re gFun::RegFun<double,>(R (__cdecl *)(void))' being compiled
    with
    [
    R=double
    ]
```

The "try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above" advice looks quite funny to me, but maybe someone can think of a modification that doesn't upset the compiler.

Comment: I've had a couple of ICEs with 2013 compiler myself. It's obviously not stable enough yet, I'm not sure it's the right idea to spend time trying to adjust to it.

Comment: As internal errors are _always_ compiler bugs, working around this issue is likely a waste of time. Just use a stable compiler.

Comment: ICEs are bugs. There's not much point in filing those on SO when you can file them on the bug tracker.

Comment: Martinho Fernandes: I'm not filing a bug, I'm searching for a workaround. Hulk: there is no "stable" Visual Studio that supports variadic templates, so following your advice means dumping Windows support for this code base for the time being. Violet: thanks for the heads up.

Comment: By the way, I wont give my personal data to MS, so if anyone wishes to use the code above for filing a bug report with them, feel free.

Comment: I've filed this in our internal database as DevDiv#811720.